# Harnack type Estimates for a p-Poisson equation with constant source term

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations, regularity

Let $B=B_1(0)\subset \mathbb R^N$ and let $u\geq 0$ solve the PDE
$$
-\Delta_p u=1\,\,\mbox{in $B$}
$$

Let another function $f$ be such that 
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta_p f =1 \;\;\mbox{in $B$}\\ 
f=0 \;\;\mbox{on $\partial B$}
\end{cases}
$$

I wish to show that in $B_{1/2}=B_{1/2}(0)$, $u-f$ satify a Harnack type estimate : 
$$
\frac{1}{C}(u-f)(0)\leq (u-f)\leq C (u-f)(0)
$$
For some $C$, an scaling invariant constant depending only on the dimension.

PS: it shall lead to same kind of estimates on $u$ because $f$ can be found explicitly as $f(x)=c(1-|x|^{p/(p-1)})$, $c$ is adjusted so that $f$ satisfy the given PDE.